# AJAX fires both success and error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure why the `error:` portion of my ajax request is also firing. Both the success and error sections are firing actually. I'm pretty new to JS/jQuery but I read that success fires when the ajax request was successful and error fires when there is an error. I assume success means 200 and error means 400-500?

js:

```
    function create_post() {
        console.log("create post is working");
        var firstName = document.getElementById("firstname");
        var lastName = document.getElementById("lastname");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phonenumber");
        var message = document.getElementById("message");
        var contactInfo = {
            "first_name": firstName.value,
            "last_name": lastName.value,
            "email": email.value,
            "phone_number": phoneNumber.value,
            "message": message.value
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "",
            type: "POST",
            data: contactInfo,
            success: ajaxSuccess(contactInfo),
            error: console.log("ajax fail")

        });
    };


    function ajaxSuccess(contactInfo) {
        console.log(contactInfo);
        // clear form data
        document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
        // display modal
    }


//    Contact form submit
    var contactForm = document.getElementById("contact-form");
    $(contactForm).on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submitted");
        create_post();
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is on these lines:

```
success: ajaxSuccess(contactInfo),
error: console.log("ajax fail")
```

This effectively running both functions immediately, and sets the return values of these functions to the `success` and `error` properties. Try using an anonymous callback function.

```
success: function() {
    ajaxSuccess(contactInfo);
},
error: function() {
    console.log("ajax fail");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, now my code is always running the success portion. But I currently do not have my backend return any status code so that might be the issue. What return codes would cause the error section to trigger? I assume 400s-500s?

Comment: @Liondancer `url: ""` will cause it to request the current page again, which presumably exists and responds with a success status code.

Comment: this is the correct answer. Success and Error should be functions. Error callback function returns three arguments: `jqXHR`, `textStatus`, `errorThrown` which can be used to communicate the error to the user.

Answer (score 5):

You are **calling** functions and passing their **return values** to `success` and `error`. You need to pass actual functions.

Since, in both cases, you are hard coding the arguments to the functions, you can use `bind` to create the new functions.

```
success: ajaxSuccess.bind(window, contactInfo),
error: console.log.bind(console, "ajax fail")
```